# Slow (repeated) Matrix Multiplication in Julia 1.0

Tags: performance, julia, matrix-multiplication

The following part in my Julia code kills all my performance:

```
        for j = 1:size(phi,3)
            for i = 1:size(phi,2)
                    phi[:,i,j] += dt*convolutionmagnitude*
                                    weightMatrix*phi[:,i,j]                     
            end
        end
```

I.e. `phi` is a three-tensor and for every `i`, `j` we want to update the first dimension by a matrix-vector product (times some scalars). `weightMatrix` is a matrix of size `size(phi,1)` by `size(phi,1)` (which might be sparse in the future). Everything happens with `floats`.

Julia allocates a lot of memory even though everything should work in place (at least I expect that). I have read through the julia documentation and found `view` but could not make use of it. How can I accelerate this computation?

Comment: It is much easier to help if you provide a self-contained minimum working example. That means that you should add input data and provide a code sample that one can simply copy-paste into a terminal, and it immediately runs.

Comment: As an example of something that is unclear now: Why isn't `dt*convolutionmagnitude` merged into `weightMatrix`? And: What is the size of `weightMatrix`? Getting answers to these questions can potentially speed up your code by one or several orders of magnitude!

Comment: @DNF, thanks for the hint. I will definitely consider that in the future! For the second part: Because `dt`and `convolutionmagnitude` might vary from time step to time step while `weightMatrix` is fixed.

Comment: If you consider it already now, it may be possible to improve performance over the answer you already got:) For example, if the size of `weightMatrix` is always 3x3, or some other small fixed number, you could use StaticArrays to speed things up significantly.

Comment: Sadly it's more in the region of 100-200 by 100-200, so as far as I understand it, StaticArrays are not the best choice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Slices (`phi[:,i,j]`) on the r.h.s. of assignments always allocate. As you said, you could use views (which aren't completely allocation free either (yet)), which should speed up things. Below I use the `@views` macro which replaces all slices by views.
- Your `+=` operation allocates as well. `a += b` is basically `a = a + b` which will allocate an array for `a+b` and then assign a to it. It is not in-place. To make it in-place you need to add a dot: `a .+= b`.
- Once your code is running you can add `@inbounds` to turn off bound checks when accessing pieces of arrays.

In total, try the following:

```
    @inbounds @views for j = 1:size(phi,3)
        for i = 1:size(phi,2)
                phi[:,i,j] .+= dt .* convolutionmagnitude .* weightMatrix * phi[:,i,j]                     
        end
    end
```

Note that this will still allocate, as it creates an intermediate vector for `weightMatrix * phi[:,i,j]`. You cannot put a dot here as this would mean element-wise multiplication rather than matrix-vector multiplication. However, you could reuse a preallocated piece of memory using `mul!` (assuming Julia >0.7 here):

```
    using LinearAlgebra # get mul!

    tmp = similar(phi[:,1,1])
    @inbounds @views for j = 1:size(phi,3)
        for i = 1:size(phi,2)
                mul!(tmp, weightMatrix, phi[:,i,j])
                phi[:,i,j] .+= dt .* convolutionmagnitude .* tmp                   
        end
    end
```

Finally, let me give you some nice reads on this:

- http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/7-julia-gotchas-handle/ (Gotcha #6)
- https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots

Disclaimer: I haven't tested any of this but just wrote it down in the text editor here, so it might contain trivial typos or similar. Nonetheless, I hope it demonstrates some issues and helps!

Comment: Thanks! Especially the dot part did a good job at speeding up the computation. I will have a look at the references.

Comment: The views there should be allocation-free because of escape analysis on v1.0.